# Как сделать дополнительный поток?

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, pyqt5, qthread

Как сделать дополнительный поток? При запуске у меня просто зависает приложение.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QThread, QObject

#import mainwindow
#import time
import sys

class MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(469, 433)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.next_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.next_button.setObjectName("next_button")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.next_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Следующая"))

class ListenThread(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def init(self):
        QThread.init(self)

    def del(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.signal.emit()
            print("test1")
            self.sleep(1)

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, MainWindow):
    def init(self):
        super().init()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.nextbutton.clicked.connect(self.gig)

    def gig(self):
        print("test2")

    def startAi(self):
        listener = ListenThread()
        listener.signal.connect(self.gig)
        listener.start()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    window.startAi()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
if name == 'main': 
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создали объект `listener = ListenThread()`. `listener` - это локальная переменная, которая удаляется сборщиком мусора.

Чтобы продлить срок ее жизни, надо сделать ее экземпляром класса.

```
self.listener = ListenThread()   # должен иметь self
```

---

```
def startAi(self):
    self.listener = ListenThread()       # + self
    self.listener.hui.connect(self.gig)
    self.listener.start()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, выручил)))